# Gulp - is there a way to add a hint or config to skip a tag and leave src="{{myImg}}"?

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

I'm trying to pack/minify a template, which should preserve Handlebars vars in it.

I can set something like `Hello \{{personName}}` and it preserves Handlebars vars and `{{#if ...}}` logic as I need it.

But for images, I need to use `src="{{myImg}}"` and can't seem to make Gulp ignore it. It always tries to find the asset and pack it.

I end up doing `src=""` and later manually editing the built file, but I'd like to stop doing that.

Comment: What package are you using to minify the code?  Some have an `ignore` option.

Comment: @Mark using gulp 4.0.2. My current solution is a `sed` script which replaces HTML after the file is built, not ideal but works fine.

Comment: Having a sample file, your sed script, and the expected output (especially where it fails) would help answer this.

Comment: @JamesRisner this is not about `sed`, that script works as intended, but it is a workaround. I'd prefer not to need it if Gulp could be instructed not to attempt to load a specific <img> src attribute as an asset.